# Is it accessible to have lists without a heading, assuming previous lists do?

Tags: accessibility, html, screen-reader

Assume this HTML structure:

```
<h2>Our latest News and Events</h2>
<ul>
  <li>news item 1</li>
  <li>news item 2</li>
  <li>news item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>event item 1</li>
  <li>event item 2</li>
</ul>
```

My question is whether the above structure is accessible and good enough, or whether I should merge the 2 lists into one so it becomes:

```
<h2>Our latest News and Events</h2>
<ul>
  <li>news item 1</li>
  <li>news item 2</li>
  <li>news item 3</li>
  <li>event item 1</li>
  <li>event item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Notes:

- In both cases the heading semantically covers all subsequent items (news and events).
- I cannot change any of the content, nor add any new headings. The data is given as is, so I can only affect the HTML (i.e combine the two lists in one).
- Both cases would have the exact same presentation (i.e there wouldn't be a visible gap between the 2 lists in the first case).

Comment: Are you able to add aria attributes to the ul's? If you can, add an aria-label attribute. If not there is not much you can do except maybe the suggestion @smuxer gave in an answer.

Comment: @jazZRo: Yes, I can add any attributes, but content is what it is. i.e I do not have the ability for any other words other what has been described. So I can only work programmatically (e.g merge lists, count items and present counts in some attribute etc).

Answer (score 2):

good question btw ;)
Grabbing your example:

```
<h2>Our latest News and Events</h2>
<ul>
  <li>news item 1</li>
  <li>news item 2</li>
  <li>news item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>event item 1</li>
  <li>event item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I used to do something more like this with sub headings to guiding the user.

```
<h2>Latest News</h2>
<ul>
  <li>news item 1</li>
  <li>news item 2</li>
  <li>news item 3</li>
</ul>

<h2>Events</h2>
<ul>
  <li>event item 1</li>
  <li>event item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Why these solution:

1. You maintain your semantic.
2. The info list are grouped by your Heading;
3. The user after the first list know immediately what kind of information is the next one.
4. It's good for multiple list (scalable).

Comment: Thanks. That combined header I use is both a client requirement and a restriction I have from the system emiting the data. Thus I'm only asking whether the 1 header and 2 lists is acceptable from an accessibility perspective.

Comment: So in that case It will be not a problem but you should use title attributes to all your list items and title.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, based on your requirements.

A screen-reader user, or any user for that matter, would have to decipher what is a news item and what is an event item.

If you can't organize them by separate lists, then maybe change the link text to make it understandable.

Ex. "News | News Item 1" or "Event | Event Item 1"

Answer (score 0):

If they are displayed visually in one group for screen users, it often means that you can use the same grouping for screen reader users too.